# (In RecyclerView Adapter) How to completely stop and start an activity when coming back to same Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

> I am moving from MainActivity to SecondActivity, As i click on the Second Activity, what can i do to completely remove the MainActivity from memory.
>
> When i press back on Second Activity to come to MainActivity then the
> MainActivity must be freshly started. How can I achieve that.
>
> Please Give Your Suggestions

Comment: below startActivity call finish in Main activity and also same in second activity

Comment: can you add your code ?

Comment: the code is simple, just wanted suggestions

Comment: else if (holder.label_bottom.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Constant.resources[0])) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,GKOuter.class);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);

Comment: how can i do this Inside Adapter class ?

Comment: kindly implement the answer posted by abdul

Comment: You can use `startActivityForResult` from `MainActivity` and when returning back call `recreate`.

Comment: can u please explain a little bit more ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `finish()` when moving from MainActivity to SecondActivity like this:

```
val i = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
startActivity(i)
finish()
```

When pressing back, override the `onBackPressed()` method and start the MainActivity again like this:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
   val i = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
   startActivity(i)
   finish()
}
```

For the given code in your Adapter given in the comments, add this:

```
else if (holder.label_bottom.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Constant.resources[0])) 
{ 
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,GKOuter.class); 
    mContext.startActivity(intent); 
    ((Activity) mContext).finish();
}
```

Comment: how can i do this Inside Adapter class ?

Comment: else if (holder.label_bottom.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(Constant.resources[0])) { Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,GKOuter.class); mContext.startActivity(intent);

Comment: How to finish inside recyclerview adapter ?

Comment: to finish from adapter val i = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        context.startActivity(i)
        (context as Activity).finish()

Comment: @Edward, please see my updated code, I updated it according to your code snippet which I believe is in your adapter. Please accept my answer by clicking the checkmark (✔️) on the left side under the vote arrows. Should change the color in green. I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To finish activity from adapter

```
    val i = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
    context.startActivity(i)
    (context as Activity).finish()
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this:-

```
                //From first activity to second
            Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);

            //from second activity to first activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: How to do this in Adapter Class of recyclerView ?

Comment: //from second activity to first activity in Adapter
   
   for example your Adapters constructor:
   ```
   Context ctx;
   
   //your adapters constructor
   myAdapter(Context ctx, Pojo pj){
    this.ctx =ctx;
   }
   
   //onCLicking pass ctx as first param to intent
   onClick(){
   
    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, FirstActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
   }
   
  ```